# What is the point of using a non-static local variable in a lock?

Tags: c#, synchronization

A couple of times I have came across this code where a local variable in a class ( its NOT a static variable) has been used in a lock.

```
 public class SomeClass
{
    private object obj = new object();
    ....
    ....
    lock(obj)
    {

    }
}
```

Is there any point of locking given that its an instance variables?

Comment: Yes,if you need to sync objects in particular instance

Comment: That's not a *local variable* (local to a single method), but a *field*, or *instance variable*.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that this might be a problem?

Comment: @Eric: Well I was actually questioning any need for this at all. It seem unnecessary to me but now looking at Jason's response (on multiple threads using same instance) re-thinking if that scenario justify use of it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is there any point of locking given that its an instance variables?

Multiple threads could be acting on the same instance and a lock is needed for thread-safety. Think, for example, of a shared queue.

Comment: So if a queue is shared, wouldn't it be better to make it static? I am just having hard time picturing this use case it in my mind. To me since any instance variables are local to that class instance, multiple threads instantiating this class will have different copy of it. What am I missing?

Comment: @imak: Think of a task queue (`class TaskQueue`). Now think of a single instance of this `TaskQueue`. Now think of it being shared among multiple threads (maybe multiple producers and multiple consumers). There is only one instance of the queue and all instance variables are shared among the various threads. An instance variable for locking is needed for making this instance "thread-safe."

Comment: @imak: To extend Jason's example: suppose you had two queues. Q1 is used on threads Alpha and Bravo. Q2 is used on threads Charlie and Delta. Why should thread Alpha accessing Q1 prevent Charlie and Delta both from accessing Q2 at the same time? That should prevent Bravo (and Charlie and Delta) from accessing Q1, but there's no reason why Charlie and Delta ought to be prohibited from accessing Q2 during that time.

Answer (score 5):

A static lock would be useful for controlling access to a static variable. An instance lock would be useful for controlling access to an instance variable.

There is no point at all in using a local lock object to protect a local variable (unless it is a captured outer variable of an anonymous function or in an iterator), since other threads will not have access to either the lock or the variable.

Comment: Unless you have a local variable that's accessed by `Action` or `Func` or anonymous methods defined in the same method.